# What is wrong with this unicode

Tags: php, unicode, encode

Ive got problem with Unicode, my client is writing text using DUNO what kind of Unicode, when he saves post  my font-family can't recognize it, here is the normal text with normal Unicode (check with chrome for better effect):

http://sa.foxiad.com/imones/1000-plyteliu-parduotuve-uab-grycia/

And here is client text:

http://sa.foxiad.com/imones/1000-smulkmenu-a-petrulio-ii/

How can i solve this, here is normal letter: ž and here is client: ž

Look at the difference.

Comment: I can't see differences. Maybe you need to explain better the place where that character is differente. I see `ž` character without problems

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Here is the link to image in sublime text http://s9.postimg.org/ucgnqody7/pvz.jpg at top there is normal text with normal lithuanian letters, and after that paragraph there is client text with circles. By the way try to paste CLIENT text to google fonts you will see the difference.

Comment: In your webpage that differences doesn't exist. You are using a typography in sublime text that's not compatible with lithuanian characters, I guess. sorry but I can't help you with this details.